# How to implement wiki-style edits in your web-application?

Tags: wiki

In a web application I am developing, I wish to implement wiki-style edits (where each and every edit is saved, can be compared, and users can rollback edits easily).

What is a good way of implementing this without re-inventing the wheel too much?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're really seeking a *Content Management System* (CMS), of which a Wiki is a specialization (IMHO).

Googling '[CMS Open Source](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-USUS292&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cms+open+source)' brings as its top hit:

[Open Source CMS](http://www.opensourcecms.com/), try before you install

- Joomla
- Drupal
- Wordpress

And a *lot* of other information.

Commercially, I really like Atlassian's [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/).  Wiki like markup, editing history, easily attach documents and now supporting editing in Word, Excel & Powerpoint.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The web application that I am developing is going to be somewhat like a CMS. I have had experience with Wordpress before, and if you save your edits, the older copy will disappear. I want it like StackOverflow where I can also undelete my posts at a later date.

Comment: The other CMS systems mentioned do provide history.  I'm not sure about the "undelete". SO seems to allow for the undelete only while you're still on the page.  Once Ive left, I don't see the "undelete" option anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have explored a little and I think CMS are not what I want. Like now, someone have edited my initial question and if I didn't like it, I have the option to roll it back. And I didn't think SO implemented some form of Open Source CMS right? SO itself is the CMS.

Answer (score 1):

use a cms like tikiwiki which is very close to what you plan todo.. :D